# Unable to install P12 certificate in Android 8.1.0

Tags: certificates

I am using an LG Aristo 2 Plus, Android 8.1.0, and have a CA and client certificate to use for a wifi network.  I have downloaded the certificates onto my phone and when I attempt to install them through:

General -> Lock screen & security -> Encryption & credentials -> Install from storage -> navigate to the files

The files are greyed out or disabled and I am unable to install them.  They're both in p12 format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be in crt format to be installed.

Comment: That was it, thanks!

Comment: @Walter kindly upvote the answer too if it helped!